# Razor MVC Drop down is not displaying selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I can successfully select a value from my drop down, and it correctly saves to the database.  However, when I return to my view page, the drop down looks like no value was previously selected.  Why is it not displaying the selected value?

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitOfMeasure",ViewData["UnitOfMeasure"] as SelectListItem[], new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
         this.ViewBag.UnitOfMeasure = this.GetUomList();
    }


        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUomList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> uomList = new List<SelectListItem>();            
        uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Select..." });

        uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CC" });
        uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CF" });
        return uomList;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by when I return to my view page? Are you doing a post in order to save it to the database? If yes, can you paste that code?

Comment: @Yogiraj - i mean, when i close the webpage, and then bring it back up.  i can see the correct value is saved in the database, but the drop down is showing "Select..." as if no previous value exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to mark the item as selected based on what you are storing in the database. Here's what you can do:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUomList()
{
    //Get selected Value or text... whatever you are storing in the db
    // I am assuming selectedText is being stored in the database
    var selectedValueOrText = GetThisFromDatabase();

    List<SelectListItem> uomList = new List<SelectListItem>();            
    uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Select..." });

    uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CC",Selected = selectedValueOrText =="CC" });
    uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CF",Selected = selectedValueOrText =="CF" });

   return uomList;
}
```

**Update**
     Alternative version of method above. (IMO improved :) )

```
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUomList()
 {
      //Get selected Value or text... whatever you are storing in the db
      // I am assuming selectedText is being stored in the database
      var selectedValueOrText = GetThisFromDatabase();
      var uomList = new List<string>
      {
          "Select...",
          "CC",
          "CF"
      };
      return uomList.Select(l => new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = l,
          Selected = selectedValueOrText == l
      });

  }
```

If you show your method to get values from the database, I can simplify / improve my answer further.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select an item with the `Selected` property:

```
uomList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CC", Selected = true });
```

Comment: won't that cause this to always be the selected item?

Comment: @devlincarnate No. The Selected property is only the initial setting. You will still be able to select other values.